# scipy.optimize.minimize fails to converge for matrix input with constraints

Tags: python, scipy, cvxpy

(First question, will edit if not good in some way. Did research prior to posting)

I want to predict x*C=y (x and y are datasets, C is a matrix), with a constraint that the rows of C sum to 1 and that its elements are between 0 and 1.

Because it's the rows that are constrained, not the columns, I can't just use linear regression and have to write down the error function.
I did this successfully in Matlab, so I know it's not in the data or method, but probably in my code.

My code (below) gives one of these two errors (depending on the random initial guess, I assume):

```
More than 3*n iterations in LSQ subproblem    (Exit mode 3)
Inequality constraints incompatible    (Exit mode 4)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to Python and spent a lot of time on this.

```
M1=data_2013.shape[1]
M2=data_2015.shape[1]

def error_function(C):
    C=C.reshape(M1,M2)
    return np.sum(np.sum((np.dot(data_2013,C)-data_2015)**2))

def between_zero_and_one(x):
    x=x.reshape(x.size)
    return x*(1-x)

def eq_constraint(x):
    x=x.reshape(M1,M2)
    return x.sum(axis=1) - 1

cons = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': between_zero_and_one}, 
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': eq_constraint}]


C0=np.random.rand(M1,M2)
result=minimize(error_function,C0, constraints=cons, options={'disp': True, 'maxiter': 10000})
```

Comment: Add the data or create reproducible synthetic-data (to show code we can run!). Mathematically it's still unclear to me what you exactly want to do. That being said, both errors seem to be something easily tackled. Furthermore the ```between_zero_and_one``` looks as worse as it gets to me. And one more thing: it's likely that this is a convex-optimization problem and you would be wise to use specialized solvers (e.g. through cvxpy).

Comment: 1. Is linking to a Kaggle notebook acceptable? It's a lot of data (around 1000-by-30), and the problem does not reproduce on a very small (e.g 2-by-3) dataset.


2. Mathematically, it's like a Markov matrix: I have a lot of state-vectors, each undergoing the (allegedly) same linear transformation that preserves their sum and has only positive values. Does this clarify?

3. Can you elaborate on 
what's wrong with 'between_zero_and_one'? Would it work better as two different constraints?


4 (and most importantly). It is indeed convex. I didn't know cvxpy, I'll read through it.

Comment: Yes. Use variable bounds if supported, or two inequalities for constraining vars between 0,1.

Comment: `cvxpy` worked and gave a proper result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sascha's answer helped me - the problem converged well with [`cvxpy`](https://www.cvxpy.org/).

Code:

```
M1=x_data.shape[1]
M2=y_data.shape[1]
C=cvx.Variable(x_data.shape[1],y_data.shape[1])
constraints=[0<=C, C<=1, cvx.sum_entries(C,axis=1)==1]
objective=cvx.Minimize(cvx.norm((x_data.values*C)-y_data.values))
prob=cvx.Problem(objective, constraints)
prob.solve()
C_mat=C.value
```

Thanks, Sascha!

Comment: I recommend using ```cvx.norm(x)``` instead of ```cvx.sum_entries(cvx.square())``` (there is even a dedicated ```cvx.sum_squares()``` function) This will be more robust and does not change the solution-vector.